# mutable default <class 'official.modeling.optimization.configs.optimizer_config.SGDConfig'> for field sgd is not allowed: use default_factory

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-addons

When I tried to train my model, I get this error:
"mutable default <class 'official.modeling.optimization.configs.optimizer_config.SGDConfig'> for field sgd is not allowed: use default_factory"

Details:

- OS: Windows
- Python: 3.11
- Tensorflow: 2.12.0
- Model: SSD MobileNet V2 FPNLite 320x320
- Full logs:
  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y4e0O.png)

Please help me!

I have searched for this error, but I haven't found any solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I just downgraded to python 3.10 and it helped.